# HTML and CSS: Show active item in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in website design and am working on designing a navigation bar using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp) tutorial. I have two files index.html and styles.css. I am taking a slightly different approach than the tutorial (I have two separate files instead of one). The contents are as follows

```css
.toplist ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1ff;
}

.toplist ul li a{
display: block;
padding: 8px 16px;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}

.toplist ul li a .active{
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}

.toplist ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}

.toplist ul li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="toplist">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

However, the part where it is supposed to show the active page in green is not working as expected. Can anyone point out whats going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed

```
.toplist ul li a.active{
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
} 
and 
<li><a class="active" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
```

```css
.toplist ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1ff;
}

.toplist ul li a{
display: block;
padding: 8px 16px;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}

.toplist ul li a.active{
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}

.toplist ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}

.toplist ul li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="toplist">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of your code is already set up. All you have to do is to update your style a bit to apply the green color to active links (`.toplist ul li a.active` instead of `.toplist ul li a .active`) and add some mechanism to add active class to currently active link.

Below is a sample of how to do it using Javascript. However, it will be better if you add the active class from your server.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.toplist ul li a');
links.forEach(function (element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // PreventDefault to prevent redirect
    e.preventDefault();
    links.forEach(function (element) {
      element.classList.remove('active');
    });
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.toplist ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: #f1f1ff;
}

.toplist ul li a{
display: block;
padding: 8px 16px;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}

.toplist ul li a.active{
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}

.toplist ul li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="toplist">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Note that I also removed the

```
.toplist ul li a:hover {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
```

style which was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the class "active" to the nav item that corresponds to the page you are currently editing. You can see this in their example: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_vertical_active

In your case, you want to add it like so:

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add class="active" for home,then it will work.